# show that Biholomorphism operates transitively

Tags: complex-analysis

I got to show two statements for the following domains: $G:=\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C\backslash\{0\}}$ and $D_1(0)$ (the circle around zero with radius 1):

(i) the group of all biholomorphic function,$Aut(G)$, operates transitively on $G$. That is for $z,w \in G$ there exists an automorphism $f \in Aut(G)$ with  $f(z)=w$.

(ii) Let $f\in Aut(G)$: If there are two points $z_1, z_2 \in G$ with $z_1\neq z_2$ and $f(z_i)=z_i$, for $i=1,2$, then $f(z)=z$ for all $z\in G$.

Have I got to find specific mappings that shows these two statements? Or is there a general proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ consists of linear maps only. In fact any entire injective function $f $ must be linear. To see this, note that such a function cannot have an essential singularity at $\infty$, by $\textbf{Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem}$. Now, that means $f$ must have a pole or a removable singualarity at $\infty$. The latter clearly implies $f$ must be constant, a contradiction. Thus $f$ has a pole at $\infty$, which means $f$ is a polynomial. The only injective polynomials are linear maps.

For $f \in\textbf{Aut}(\mathbb{C_*})$, we argue similarly. $f$ has either a pole or a removable singularity at $0$. We reduce the former case to the latter in the following sense: If $f$ has a pole at $0$, consider $g(z)=\dfrac{1}{f(z)}$. Now $g\in \textbf{Aut}(\mathbb{C_*})$ and has a removable singularity at $0$.

Thus, it only remains to determine all $f\in\textbf{Aut}(\mathbb{C_*})$ with a removable singularity at $0$. Proceed in the same way as in this question, [Automorphism of unit disk without zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835944/automorphism-of-unit-disk-without-zero), to conclude that $f$ is again a linear map with constant term zero.

Finally, one has a fairly clear description of $\textbf{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$. They are precisely the Blaschke Products, see here: http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/rc476/complexanalysis/autD.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Part (ii) is false for $G= \mathbb{C\backslash\{0\}}$. Let $\phi(z)=1/z$; then $\phi$ is a non-trivial automorphism with two fixed points.