# existence of an automorphism F(A)=A

Tags: complex-analysis

Let G be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $A\subset G$ be finite.I got to show that for every $f\in Aut(G\backslash A)$ there is a unique $F \in Aut (G)$ with $F\vert_{G\backslash A}=F$ and that $F(A)=A$. $Aut$ is the group of all automorphism. I got no idea how to show this. Can I use here the Maximums-theorem?

Comment: $\textbf{Hint:}$ Proceed exactly as in here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835944/automorphism-of-unit-disk-without-zero.

Comment: Also please consider accepting answers as it reduces the amount of "unanswered" questions.

Comment: @Hmm. He can't accept any answers until he's done asking every question in the universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same argument as for several of your recent questions. If $a\in A$ then $f$ has a removable singularity at $a$ since $G$ is bounded. So $f$ extends to a map $F:G\to\overline G$. Open Mapping Thorem shows that $F:G\to G$.

If $a\in A$ and $F(a)\in G$ then the Open Mapping Theorem shows that $f$ is not injective. So $F$ maps $A$ into $A$. And if $a,a'\in A$, $a\ne a'$ and $F(a)=F(a')$ then the Open Mapping Theorem shows that $f$ is not injective. So $F$ is injective on $A$; since $A$ is finite it follows that $F$ is bijective.

For details see my answer to your other question [Automorphism of unit disk without zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835944/automorphism-of-unit-disk-without-zero)